# How to get all values from the range of cells? (B3:D5)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets

I have a range of cells: B3:D5.
How can I get all values from this range? - ["B3", "C3", "D3", "B4", "C4", "D4", "B5", "C5", "D5"];

Comment: share  you code aswell

Comment: As Nikkkshit mentioned can you please share your existing codes if there is? Also wanted to confirm this is using node.js and not appscript?

Answer (score 0):

**This is for Reading a Single range**

```
gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
  spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
  range: range
}).then((response) => {
  var result = response.result;
  var numRows = result.values ? result.values.length : 0;
  console.log(`${numRows} rows retrieved.`);
});
```

**This is for Reading Multiple ranges**

```
var ranges = [
  // Range names ...
];
gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGet({
   spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
   ranges: ranges
}).then((response) => {
  var result = response.result;
  console.log(`${result.valueRanges.length} ranges retrieved.`);
});
```

Read their Documentation :
**https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#javascript**